# What are the possible residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

Should be a simple question but I'm not exactly sure what it's asking.
If $x  \equiv a\ (mod \ m)$, then $a$ is called a residue of $x$ to modulus $m$.

So if we know $x \equiv 2\ (mod \ 5)$, what does it mean to ask the possible of residues of $x\ mod\ 15$? Or $16$?

Comment: Hint. Write out the list of numbers congruent to $2$ mod $5$. Look for patterns. Then look for patterns mod $15$.

Comment: So numbers of the form 5n + 2. But what does it mean to get possible residues when you switch 'moduli'?

Comment: Write them down: $2, 7, 12, 17, 22, \ldots$ and see what can happen  mod $15$. When you figure it out you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: $x$ is an integer. It tells you what $x$ is mod $5$, your task is to figure out what it could be mod $15$ or $16$  from that information.

Comment: Oh so if x is an integer of form 5n + 2, all the question is asking is the possible residues mod 15/16 of x. So a) 2, 7, 12, b) 2, 7, 12, 1, 6, 11, 0, 5, 10, 15, 4, 9, 14, 3, 8, 13. Sorry for the silly question!